# PHP regexp - remove unused constrain from query string

Tags: php, sql, regex

**Background**

I am working on a small piece of code that will iterate through fields of some dynamically created form and create database select from them.

```
SELECT some_col FROM some_tab WHERE col1=%fieldName1 AND col2=%fieldName2 AND col3=%fieldName3
```

I iterate through fields of form and I am replacing "%fieldName?" with value stored in a particular field. My problem is that not all fields mentioned in the query string could be listed in the form. So after replacing some field names with values, I want to remove rest of them from the query string.

**Question**

I want to remove a string that starts with "AND ", ends with " " and contains "=%". Can you help me, please?

Comment: To purely address you question, you could try `^AND.*%.* $`. However, as your AND is contained in a string (and is not a string itself), something like this should be more apropriate : `AND .*%.* `

Comment: `AND [a-zA-Z0-9=]*%[a-zA-Z0-9=]* ?` would be better yet

Comment: I misread your question, and didn't see you wanted your expression to always contain `=%` (mine checks for always `%`, but would validate an expression without an equal sign, and even with 2 or 3 equals). You should use `AND \w*=%\w* ?` instead. \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~AND.*?=%\S*[ ]~', '', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- `AND` matches the literal `AND`
- `.*?` lazily matches everything up to...
- the literal `=%`
- `\S*` matches any chars that are not spaces
- `[ ]` matches one space (the brackets are not needed but make it easier to spot)
- We replace with the empty string

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
$query=preg_replace('% AND [a-z0-9A-Z]+\=\%[^\s]+%','',$query);
```